# How to update nested Objects

Tags: express, vue.js, mongoose

I want to use the $push method to push an object into a nested array. But i cant get it to work that you can dynamically get the right object inside of the array. Let me explain better by showing the code.

This is my Schema:

```
var StartedRaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    waypoints: {
        type: Object,
        name: String,
        check_ins: {
            type: Object,
            user: {
                type: Object,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When you check in on a waypoint, it has to be pushed in the correct waypoints nested Check_ins

This is the code for the update:

```
StartedRace.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
        { $push: { 'waypoints.1.check_ins': req.body.user } },
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    error: error
                })
            } else {
                res.send({
                    success: true
                })
            }
        }
    )
```

As you can see i can only get it to work with fields like:

```
'waypoints.1.check_ins'
```

That 1 needs to be dynamically because it gets send within the parameters.
But i can not get it to work dynamically, only hard coded.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If `req.params.id` contains the number, you would do this:  { ['waypoints.' + req.params.id + '.check_ins']: req.body.user }

Answer (score 0):

Populate the collection with a list of `check_ins` enumerated by their ids.

```
  waypoints.check_ins = {
      ...waypoints.check_ins,
      [response.id]: response
  }
```

You'd then have a list of `check_ins` that can referenced by their ids.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this syntax instead of the dot notation:

```
    let id = req.params.id;
    StartedRace.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
      { $push: { waypoints: { id: { check_ins: req.body.user } } } }, { new : true } )
        .exec()
        .then(race => console.log(race))
        .catch(err => err);
```

I used a Promise, but it's the same with a callback.